# Mercury installation

Tags: mercury

I already download Mercury 11.07.1 from
http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/download/release.html

and also installed cygwin on my Windows 7 PC. However i don't know how to install the mercury. Is there anyone can help me with the installation guide?

Comment: There should be classic `./configure` and `make install` steps

Answer (score 4):

If you unzip the Mercury download, you'll find a dozen or so README files in the new directory.

There's one called README.Cygwin, there's also some other Windows related files.  These should contain instructions and information to get you started. (open them with notepad)